# Can't send HID feature reports of more than 64 bytes on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, usb, hid

I have a device which exposes MaxFeatureReportSize = 263. The protocol for communicating with the device requires me to send feature reports with length of exactly 263 bytes. This works fine on Windows, but I ran into a strange problem on Mac - `IOHIDDeviceSetReport` on OS X 10.11 and 10.12 returns cryptic error `0xe0005000` which I couldn't deduce from IOKit headers, and code for corresponding driver (`IOUSBHostHIDDevice`) is closedsource.

Further investigation showed that

1. The error doesn't appear when sending requests of 64 bytes or less. Unfortunately, this doesn't really help because the protocol is set in stone and I cannot change it - I have to send 263 bytes.
2. On OS X 10.10 which uses old `IOUSBHIDDriver` instead of `0xe0005000` I get `0xe000404f` error. This is `kIOUSBPipeStalled`, but I still get it every time I try to send more than 64 bytes.

This is as far as I got. I'm now considering downloading OS X 10.8 and debugging IOUSBFamily to see why it can't handle more than 64 byte reports. It's a shame that Apple chose to remove IOUSBFamily sources from OS X 10.9 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardware protocol analyzer finally uncovered what was wrong with Mac packets. All Mac packets were 263 bytes long (exactly what I set them to be), while some Windows packets were truncated to 64 bytes (by the system!). As soon as I added a hack to truncate these packets on Mac it worked flawlessly.

I don't know why Windows decided to truncate them - maybe because of a specific report ID (something in a descriptor?), or maybe because the actual packet length never exceeded 20 bytes and everything else was padding. But this weird behavior was actually the one that device was expecting.

Answer (score 2):

`IOKit/usb/IOUSBHostFamily.h` (should be inside Xcode.app) defines the error `0xe0005000` to be `kUSBHostReturnPipeStalled`.

- Do you have a hardware protocol analyzer to see what's happening on the wire?
- Apple used to have "log releases" of IOUSBFamily ([downloadable here)](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) that allowed further debugging. The last version was for 10.9.4, it might be helpful to get 10.9 and install it.
- The `lists.apple.com` site has been down for a few days, but someone on the USB list may be able to help. You may be able to join the list now by emailing "help" in the subject or body to `Usb-request@lists.apple.com`
- I was searching and found this thread that might be useful (although it's operating below the HID Manager level): [Stall reported by ReadPipe, but no stall in USB Protocol Capture](http://www.mail-archive.com/usb@lists.apple.com/msg00205.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it turned out protocol analyzer was the way to go. I posted my own answer with my findings. Also, IOUSBFamily 10.9.4 release is incomplete with pieces of code missing, I guess that's why it's not listed under OS X 10.9.4.